# ElectronJS electron-builder build error in Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, electron, electron-builder

I followed a blog titled [Creating an Electron Application for the Raspberry Pi](https://azukidigital.com/blog/2019/electron-application-on-raspberry-pi/), regarding starting an Electron app in Raspberry Pi using the Buster OS and got it to compile.

But when it came to building the application, using the electron-builder, I keep getting the error of cannot execute... after running the command `electron-builder --dir --armv7l --linux deb` and can't figure what the issue is. I've attached the error [image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to be 6 months late to the party, but I also just tried to create an Electron app to run on the Raspberry Pi.

It turns out that while Electron *runs* fine on Arm processors, there are a bunch of problems with building an Electron app via electron-builder on an Arm processor.

The error that you are seeing is just the opening of the rabbit-hole.

Most of the issues appear to be due to electron-builder having apparently been implemented on an x86 machine, with no real care having been taken to make sure that it works on any other architecture - x86 is just pretty-much assumed.

So, for me, the answer was to build the Arm target on an x86 Linux machine, using exactly the same command-line that you used.

So far, I have found that I can build for OS X and Windows on OS X, for Linux x86, Linux Arm, OS X, and Windows on Linux x86. I don't have Windows machine, so I'm not sure what actually works there.

Code signing is yet another rabbit hole....

Comment: Pardon my delayed response as well, I haven't checked stack overflow in some time. Thank you for the feedback, it really brings clarity on how to fix the issue. I did encounter a question previously with the same solution, of compiling it on another machine, but then encountered another issue where an arm CPU needed to be present, and got stuck on a virtual machine trying to mimic the environment. I will try again, I hope there have been some good changes since then. Thanks again!